# why oracle is inserting "hh24:mi:ss" like a date "dd/mm/yyy"

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I need to run this sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO JSP_CONTROL (estado,hora_inicio,fecha,tipo) VALUES
('ACTUALIZANDO',to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:mi:SS'),sysdate,'uno');
```

this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "GCUENTAS"."JSP_CONTROL"
(
"ESTADO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
"HORA_INICIO" TIMESTAMP (6),
"HORA_TERMINO" TIMESTAMP (6),
"FECHA" DATE,
"TIPO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

The problem is here:  to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:mi:SS'), it's supposed to insert something like "16:01:35", but insert "16/01/35" (in DD/MM/YY format).

making some test like

SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:mi:SS') FROM DUAL

are succesfull

This is the message error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando:
INSERT INTO JSP_CONTROL (estado,hora_inicio,fecha,tipo) VALUES
  ('ACTUALIZANDO',to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:mi:SS'),sysdate,'uno')
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-01843: mes no válido
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando:
INSERT INTO JSP_CONTROL (estado,hora_inicio,fecha,tipo) VALUES
  ('ACTUALIZANDO',to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:mi:SS'),sysdate,'uno')
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-01843: mes no válido
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: A `timestamp(6)` contains a day and a time with 6 digits of precision on the seconds.  It doesn't make sense to use `sysdate` to populate `hora_termino` since `sysdate` doesn't have fractional seconds-- it would be much more logical to use `systimestamp` or `current_timestamp` for that.  It makes no sense to assign a character string to `hora_inicio` and it makes even less sense to try to assign just a time component.  Since there must be a day component, today's date will be used so, if that worked, you'd just be back to assigning `sysdate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hora_inicio` is a timestamp column, but you are passing a character value to it in the insert statement because of the `to_char()` call.

While processing the character value you provided Oracle tries to convert it into a timestamp (because the target column *is* a timestamp). But a time like `23:56:12` is most definitely not a valid date.

If you are trying to insert **only** the time part into that column, that won't work. A timestamp *always* contains a date. There is no datatype in Oracle to only hold a time.

Comment: Well, if the intention is to store a duration rather than a time, you could use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.

Comment: "There is no datatype in Oracle to only hold a time."
thk for that, I'm going to save the time like a varchar.